# What is the difference between RemoteServiceServlet and RemoteService?

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt

I know that the first one is a class and the second is an interface but the point is, 
why should client Services extends the **RemoteService** and for the **ServiceImpl** class extends **RemoteServiceServlet**

So What is Actually behind the Scene ?!

Comment: Your question is not clear. By the way, RemoteServiceServlet implements RemoteService as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to compare apples and oranges. Please read [docs](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideRemoteProcedureCalls) and make any simple demo [project](https://www.google.by/#q=gwt+rpc+example) to clearly understand these concepts.

**RemoteService** is the interface that RPC interfaces on client side should extend. And **RemoteServiceServlet** is the servlet base class for your RPC service implementations on the server. It deserializes requests from the client and serializes outgoing responses.

To use the RPC you need create and define in the `client` package own interface should extend the [RemoteService](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService.html) interface and specifies methods the server should implement.

```
package com.yourproject.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;

public interface CustomInfoService extends RemoteService {
    Info getInfo(String infoId);
}
```

Then you need provide implementation of this interface by server side. This should be a servlet in `server` package which extends [RemoteServiceServlet](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet.html) and implements the `CustomInfoService`.

```
package com.yourproject.server;

import com.yourproject.client.CustomInfoService;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

public class InfoServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements CustomInfoService {
   public Info getInfo(String infoId) {
       //implementation (for example getting info from database)
   }
}
```

Sure to work properly you also need set the servlet mapping, create an asynchronous interface, make its call and process a result in a generated callback, implement the interface [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) or [IsSerializable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable.html) for classes of instances which are pass over the RPC.

Answer (score 3):

**RemoteService** is a marker interface that allow GWT to find your RPC/RPCAsync interfaces (to validate them/do the link with your implementation).

**RemoteServiceServlet** is the servlet that receive the call from the client, deserialize the parameters, call your method, serialize what is returned by your method (exception or returned object), and send it to the client.