# Server Side Implementation in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am writing code in the server package in GWT. When I call a method in the server where the method implementation is the client package, my program works just fine. However, when I want to call a method that is in a different package all together, I get a "unable to get server response". Any ideas?

For instance, if I have a method in the server side, where foo() implementation is located in the client package in a seperate class, it works. If foo() is located in a different package however, it doesnt work.

Edit:[What is the difference between RemoteServiceServlet and RemoteService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372633/what-is-the-difference-between-remoteserviceservlet-and-remoteservice) states that RPC should be defined in the client package. Is there any way to define it in any package outside or any package remotely created?

Comment: Why do you put server logic to client package? It is intended for client side, as it name says, for translating to javascript.

Comment: the server calls a method foo() that does some random stuff and foo() is located the client  package. Howerver, I want foo() implementation to be located in a class outside of this package. I want the server to call foo() which would be located somewhere else.

Comment: May be it's better to locate it in `shared` package?

Comment: I already took a look at that solution but the client never users foo(). Basically my problem is this: my server calls foo() where the client has a class called test with one method    public void foo() {print("hi")}. However, I dont want this method in client package but want it in another package say overflow.testing.test where I can just import that package in the server side and just call it normally.

Comment: Generally you can use any package. What error occurs?

Comment: A stack trace could be useful.

Comment: Unable to obtain server response: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeExceception: 500. The call failed on the server; see server log for details

Comment: the log basically states SEVERE:Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call

Comment: There must be another stack trace entries.